# Creating EMP emittor, is this capacitor good?

Tags: capacitor, wire, supercapacitor, copper

I'm creating an EMP and i was wondering what the discharge on this capacitor is: [1 x Castle Cap Pack (50v, 12s LiPo, 880 Farads)](https://www.modelsport.co.uk/castle-cap-pack-50v-12s-lipo-880-farads-/rc-car-products/368567)

-Its used for helicopters and airplanes so surely this would be good for a fast discharge?

Also, 880 Farads sounds like a VERY LARGE load of capacitance? -Is this legit?

I am also using a 9volt battery that i think the purpose of is to charge the capacitor until the switch is turned On so it releases 880 Farads of current through the copper wire and create an Electromagnetic Pulse.

-Am I right with this theory?

I am also using [THIS](http://uk.farnell.com/pro-power/ecw1-5/wire-32m-1-5mm-copper-transparent/dp/1230987?mckv=RF5ekxVt_dc%7Cpcrid%7C78108291309%7C&gross_price=true&CATCI=aud-294759717834:pla-131288067669&CAAGID=14983536189&CMP=KNC-GUK-GEN-SHOPPING-PRO_POWER&CAGPSPN=pla&gclid=Cj0KEQjwldzHBRCfg_aImKrf7N4BEiQABJTPKAIpcVYqzQM7ZwRZwli4sU1p-MJ6gtTOVFzt4MZ_V80aAtGl8P8HAQ&DM_PersistentCookieCreated=true&CAWELAID=120173390000034025) copper wire, will this be suitable?

I'd be very appreciative if you gave me your thoughts and opinions, we are also building this with our 9th Grade Physics teacher. Thanks.

Comment: microFarads maybe, but who's bothered about 6 orders of magnitude. EMP needs a higher voltage, kV would be better.

Comment: Looks like a typo. Those caps look like they could easily be 220uF/50V. [Here's a 1F, 35V cap. $226, 10" long](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/capacitors/aluminum-capacitors/58?k=&pkeyword=&pv63=371&FV=34014b%2Cffe0003a&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500)

Comment: Thats not a capacitor, its a lipo battery pack. It has roughly the equivalent of 880 farads

Comment: @laptop2d actually, it's a storage cap pack for a LiPO-operated R/C vehicle. .. AzAzMaTr0n, notice that it's intended for *remote controlled* helicopters and airplanes ;)

Comment: CASTLE 011-0002-02 CASTLE CREATIONS CAPACITOR PACK. 12S MAX 50.0V. 1100UF http://www.modelengines.com.au/retail_catalogue_27/CASTLE-011-0002-02-CASTLE-CREATIONS-CAPACITOR-PACK-12S-MAX-500V-1100UF_item.html?ref_cat_id=BPDJ

Comment: With that said, there's ***no possible way*** that they're advertising that pack correctly. Those look like Aluminum Electrolytic caps, but for a 48.6V cap set to reach even 166F, you end up with a monstrosity that's 42x19x18cm using EDL caps, and at a cost of ~$1,300USD. ...More likely the pack's capacity is 0.000880F!

Comment: Definitely mis-advertising if not false advertising. Notice that the pic has all of the caps labels pointed away so you can't see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put: 880 farad in that size is complete bull. It's most likely _micro_farad, 880 µF. That makes the voltage rating credible, judging from the size of the capacitors.

As [Neil_UK](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/300499/creating-emp-emittor-is-this-capacitor-good#comment692187_300499) states: You want a higher voltage than a 9 volt battery for this project.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the help, why tf is my post -2 lmao? Also what voltage would you recommend for an EMP? Whats more important? Voltage or Farads and how do I find how fast a capacitor discharges?